# Angular2 - System is not defined when using out angular-cli

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have been working with angular-cli to create a sample project, understanding that this tool is just for compiling and generating an embebed server for test.
However when I open the files inside dist folder without any server but the browser, I got many problems because it can get the files, specially this message:

> ReferenceError: System is not defined

If I try to open the project using tomcat for example I see this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [imgsafe.org](https://i.imgsafe.org/77a2ca57d4.png))</sub>

Then I tried to rewrite manually the directories to get these files and then I got this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [imgsafe.org](https://i.imgsafe.org/77ab16c03e.png))</sub>

Inside the index.html

```
    <script>
      System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
        System.import('main');
      }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

I can keep rewriting... but then I got more and more errors for the same reason.
So I don't have any clue how to solve this and I can't find a good example.

I can't depend of a Node server and since this is just JavaScript code for the side client it should be work even without any server.

I would apreciate any suggest or idea.

**EDIT**: I have tried `ng serve`and that is how I know the app works, but I need to use it in other server like tomcat.

Comment: You need a basic http-server atleast, to run the Angular2 app. I use `http-server` which is again an npm module. But it is bare minimum http server which can serve any folder. In production most likely you will have apache or ngninx to serve these files

Comment: @Siraj that is what I tried tomcat, this is just client-side code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this as I was expecting, using a CDN.
I took as base the example from Angular documentation: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

```
var  map = {
'app':                        'app',
'@angular':                   'https://npmcdn.com/@angular', // sufficient if we didn't pin the version
'@angular/router':            'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/router' + routerVer,
'@angular/forms':             'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/forms' + formsVer,
'@angular/router-deprecated': 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/router-deprecated' + routerDeprecatedVer,
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'https://npmcdn.com/angular2-in-memory-web-api', // get latest
'rxjs':                       'https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6',
'ts':                         'https://npmcdn.com/plugin-typescript@4.0.10/lib/plugin.js',
'typescript':                 'https://npmcdn.com/typescript@1.9.0-dev.20160409/lib/typescript.js'
};
```

This is from the system config file. 
Using it this way now I can open my project using tomcat or another application server or even just from the web browser. Thank you for all the good ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the same reason they have given the command

```
ng serve
```

Use that and it will give you an address something like 'http://localhost:port/' and once you access it it will run your sample app.

angular 2 does not work well when you think of it as file system and open index.html on it's own. maybe in future you could but as of now, I do not know of any other way.

**Edit**: The other way I use is create a website in IIS and give physical path to **dist** folder and whenever you will do ***ng build*** you will be able to open the app.

Comment: I forgot to say that is obviously how I tested the app that creates angular-cli, using `ng serve`. But I need to use tomcat since it has to make request to a Java application.

Comment: do you really need to use tomcat? u can use ng serve on your webserver and open the ports for the website. and you can call your Java application via API/Rest calls?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that is my only option, this needs to be a single project, the angular part must be just the presentation. What I believe now is that the problem occurs because the way webservers identify relative paths, since tomcat is not an http server it can't gets the files stored on it, so my next try is to use a CDN to get those files.

Answer (score 0):

Angular-cli is a tool that effectively takes all those configuration and setup steps, condenses it down into one quick line with `ng new project_name`. So it provides you scalable project structure, instead it handles all common tedious tasks for you out of the box.

And really cool thing is that, CLI allows us to do is to serve our application in the browser. Previously, we would have to create a server using lite-server or create our own Node (or other) server.The Angular CLI does this with one simple command:

```
ng build
```

Above command will build your project inside /dist folder, it outputs 3 different files and assets by default.

- vendor.js (Concatenated 3rd party libraries).
- vendor.css(Concatenated 3rd party css files).
- app.js (Concatenated version of your controllers, directives and other entities. )
- app.css(Concatenated version of styles). index.html (Your main html file).

And to open it in the browser -

```
ng serve
```

It works same as build command, in addition it runs a local server with livereload.

Angular-cli is based on [ember-cli](https://ember-cli.com/). Ember CLI’s runtime is configurable via a file named `.ember-cli`. The JSON-formatted file, which must be placed in your home directory, can include any command-line options. This is the reason we can able to run angular-cli project in browser

It's important to take note of this directory structure and where the files are located because the application that the Angular CLI generates follows the recommended app structure and style guide.

Comment: I completely understand this behavior, I thought it could just work moving the _dist_ content to another server like tomcat, but as far I tried it didn't work